# what is the eipp.log.xz file?

Tags: debian, logs

I found on my debian stretch based raspberry system a file named *eipp.log.xz*.
Located at */var/log/apt/*.

I was wondering what it is.

From the *authlog*, around the creation time, I found something that it maybe is something from "debian-security-support" ?

```
Mar 16 06:49:18 pi su[22037]: Successful su for debian-security-support by root
Mar 16 06:49:18 pi su[22037]: + ??? root:debian-security-support
Mar 16 06:49:18 pi su[22037]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user debian-security-support by (uid=0)
Mar 16 06:49:19 pi systemd-logind[247]: New session c116 of user debian-security-support.
Mar 16 06:49:19 pi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user debian-security-support by (uid=0)
Mar 16 06:49:21 pi su[22037]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user debian-security-support
Mar 16 06:49:21 pi systemd-logind[247]: Removed session c116.
Mar 16 06:49:22 pi su[23052]: Successful su for debian-security-support by root
Mar 16 06:49:22 pi su[23052]: + ??? root:debian-security-support
Mar 16 06:49:22 pi su[23052]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user debian-security-support by (uid=0)
Mar 16 06:49:22 pi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user debian-security-support
Mar 16 06:49:22 pi systemd-logind[247]: New session c117 of user debian-security-support.
Mar 16 06:49:22 pi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user debian-security-support by (uid=0)
Mar 16 06:49:25 pi su[23052]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user debian-security-support
Mar 16 06:49:26 pi systemd-logind[247]: Removed session c117.
```

Should I be worried?

thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You needn’t be worried, this file is used by `apt`’s planner. It doesn’t have anything to do with `debian-security-support` (which is also OK, it comes from the eponymous package).

`eipp.log.xz` is part of the “External Installation Planner Protocol”, which is an interface between APT, external planning tools (including APT itself), and `dpkg`. It was implemented as part of [David Kalnishkies’ GSoC 2016 project](https://david.kalnischkies.de/blog/tags/gsoc2016/); a short description from [the initial commit](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/commit/7b197262212f49b3b355b1124edf2ba9adb73411) gives some background:

> APT-based tools like apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, … work with the user to figure out how their system should look like after they are done installing/removing packages and their dependencies. The actual installation/removal of packages is done by dpkg with the constrain that dependencies must be fulfilled at any point in time (e.g. to run maintainer scripts).
>
> Historically APT has a super micro-management approach to this task which hasn't aged that well over the years mostly ignoring changes in dpkg and growing into an unmaintainable mess hardly anyone can debug and everyone fears to touch – especially as more and more requirements are tacked onto it like handling cycles and triggers, dealing with "important" packages first, package sources on removable media, touch minimal groups to be able to interrupt the process if needed (e.g. unattended-upgrades) which not only sky-rocket complexity but also can be mutually exclusive as you e.g. can't have minimal groups and minimal trigger executions at the same time.

This work is what led to the more constrained installation and upgrade process you’ll see in current versions of APT, particularly visible with the renamed packages you’ll see being passed to `dpkg`, with an added ordering number.

Comment: can I disable the file `/var/log/apt/eipp.log.xz` completely? I don't want this information to be logged, it has no use for me.

Comment: @Martin I haven’t tested this, but you should be able to disable it by adding `Dir::Log::Planner "/dev/null";` to your APT configuration (in a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`).